# Are we not encouraged to write XML configuration using Maven + Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Currently learning to build spring apps. I have been quite sucessful deploying mock applications for now, but one thing has been annoying me, which is not understanding the mechanisms behind the numerous annotations we add to the code. Look, I'm not saying I don't know which purpose they serve, where they act, nor am I questioning their helpfulness.

My point is that I feel that skipping the changes that should be made (or are being made?) in the XML files actually makes me feel that at the end of the day I don't know what I am truly writing. Let me be more specific, so you could answer me with regards to the following example. This is from Spring manual.

> Let’s assume we have the following configuration that defines firstMovieCatalog as the primary MovieCatalog

```html
@Configuration
public class MovieConfiguration {
@Bean
@Primary
public MovieCatalog firstMovieCatalog() { ... }
@Bean
public MovieCatalog secondMovieCatalog() { ... }
// ...
}
```

> With such configuration, the following MovieRecommender will be autowired with the
> firstMovieCatalog.

```html
public class MovieRecommender {
@Autowired
private MovieCatalog movieCatalog;
// ...
}
```

> The corresponding bean definitions appear as follows.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="example.SimpleMovieCatalog" primary="true">
<!-- inject any dependencies required by this bean -->
</bean>
<bean class="example.SimpleMovieCatalog">
<!-- inject any dependencies required by this bean -->
</bean>
<bean id="movieRecommender" class="example.MovieRecommender"/>
</beans>
```

Okay, so, I think if you can answer me 2 questions regarding this example, It would clear a lot the understanding I am lacking here.

1. The first thing that is not clear for me: is the annotation process a SEPARATED process from the XML configuration, or is it GENERATING this equivalent XML configuration in some hidden fashion?
2. Where actually IS this XML configuration file? All spring applications I generated through Initializr just generate the pom.xml file, and it does not include  configuration. If I were not using the annotations, would I have to manually write an equivalent configuration in the pom?

Comment: XML configuration is old style. Ignore it.

Comment: So annotations actually don't generate XML, but only Java code per se?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Annotations don't generate code either

Comment: I believe the reason they show the XML config along with the Java config is to help those who understand or are still using XML config to migrate to Java config.  One big benefit of Java config is that it provides compile-time type safety. Personally I think one or more `@Configuration` files is much more maintainable than one or more XML configuration files.

Comment: One of the core concepts of Spring DI is that it is _declarative_; your `MovieRecommender` says (via its constructor parameter, for example) that it needs _some_ `MovieCatalog`, and Spring takes care of analyzing your context and determining that `SimpleMovieCatalog` is available to inject. XML and JavaConfig are just two of the ways to explain to Spring what items are available and required.

Comment: If I can ask something based on @LuiggiMendoza 's response: so what, indeed, these annotations generate? Because when I look into .xml files I can imagine there exists some kinds of procedural algorithm within the JVM that reads the file content and "knows how act". So, with annotations, the same must be happening somehow, isn't it?

Comment: That procedural algorithm is bundled within Spring's jar, not JVM. What happens under the hood is [`reflection`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html), which Spring uses to generate instances with class metadata, fires field injection, and other "magic tricks".

Answer (score 1):

> is the annotation process a SEPARATED process from the XML configuration, or is it GENERATING this equivalent XML configuration in some hidden fashion?

Spring is not generating any XML or annotation in any case. Spring use XML and annotation processing to get info about which components (classes) are available to use and which beans (instances) to create, inject and use for processing. Then, all these beans could be retrieved by application context (not to confuse with xml of the same name).

> Where actually IS this XML configuration file?

Spring first version used XML to configure your app. Later (starting in Spring 3), Spring added annotation support and processing to *ease* application configuration. Annotations are just another way to configure your components and beans without the hassle of maintaining big XML files (over 1000 lines or even more) or just to avoid dealing with XML at all. Current Spring versions support both configurations, you could also use a mix: using XML and using annotations.

Note that Spring's [`ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) has several implementations with different entry points for configuration:

- `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` accepts a class decorated with `@Configuration`.
- `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` accepts the path of a XML file available in application classpath.

---

> If I were not using the annotations, would I have to manually write an equivalent configuration in the pom?

First thing first: POM files are for maven processing, not for Spring. Since you're using Maven, and you want to try using a Spring Boot application without annotations, then you can have this project structure:

```
- src
  - main
    - java
      /* your Java packages and files */
      - com.example
        + App   <--- Main entry point
      - com.example.service
        + Car    <--- Component 1
        + Engine <--- Component 2
    - resources
      + my-beans.xml <--- XML configuration. Name can be anything
```

App class:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.service.Car;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:my-beans.xml")
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        Car car = ctx.getBean(Car.class);
        car.move();
    }
}
```

Car.class:

```
package com.example.service;

public class Car {

    private Engine engine;

    public void move() {
        engine.start();
    }
}
```

Engine.class:

```
package com.example.service;

public class Engine {

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("engine starts");
    }
}
```

my-beans.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    
    <bean class="com.example.service.Engine" />

    <bean class="com.example.service.Car" />
        <property name="engine" ref="engine"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This is truly valuesome. Just you explaning that .xml configuration should be written inside Resources kind of clarified the world for me. I can't understand why people don't mention such basic things when explaining Spring.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This clarified a lot to me. These things have become increadibly complicated to learn nowadays because most people teaching MVC concepts are completely focused in teach you "getting things working". So at least I find it quite difficult to encounter sources of knowledge that are concerned to explain the mechanisms in a didatic manner.

Answer (score 0):

> is the annotation process a SEPARATED process from the XML configuration, or is it GENERATING this equivalent XML configuration in some hidden fashion

When you initialize a Spring application, you instantiate an `ApplicationContext`: it's responsible to load all the context definition (the beans, services...).

`ApplicationContext` is actually an interface which has several implementations depending on how your context is defined:

- `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` which reads an XML file
- `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` for annotations based approach
- ...

Thus you can see it as a unique process, only the datasource is different: either XML or annotations. But they describe the same thing: a context.